# How do I represent this model in tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table of warehouses and a table of clients to manage several warehouses belonging to different clients

```
warehouse
=====
id
address
capacity
owner_client


client
=====
id
name
```

My issue is, i have an ACME client, and ACME has an "ACME safety rating" attribute only applicable to their warehouses.  Currently we just have this as a field of warehouses and its null for non-acme warehouses.  But this feels wrong and has required some workarounds and special cases.

Whats the best way to represent this?  I've thought of making an "Acme safety ratings" table with the number and FK to the warehouse, but now I've made a table specific for one client?  What if we need to start tracking "is_foobar_accesible" for the baz client?

Comment: Are you likely to have other unique attributes?  I'd probably make an `Attributes` table, with fk to the warehouse, an attribute name column, and an attribute value column.  Then you can left join to that to pick up any attributes you may be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationally pure way to do this would be to implement your initial suggestion i.e. have a separate table such as ACME_WAREHOUSES that holds the attributes such as SAFTEY_RATING that are only applicable to this client. A different CLIENT_WAREHOUSES table would be created for each client that has its own attributes. In this way you could use standard database constraint functionality to ensure the integrity of the data in these tables.

Another method would be to add a series of nullable columns to the WAREHOUSES table such as ACME_SAFETY_RATING and BAZ_FOOBAR_ACCESSIBLE. This is not relationally pure as it means null values can exist in this table. However, you can still use standard database functionality to ensure the integrity of the data. It can be a bit more convoluted if certain values are mandatory in certain situations. Also, if there are many clients with many differing attributes the number of columns in the table can become unwieldy.

Another method is the Entity-Attribute-Value model. Generally, this is to be avoided if at all possible. It is not relationally pure, as your column values are now no longer defined over domains, and it is extremely difficult, if not impossible, to ensure the integrity of the data. Any real attempt to do so will require a lot of bespoke coding (which needs to be carefully implemented to cater for things like concurrency control that database constraints give you for free) as you cannot use standard database constraints. However, if you are just interested in storing values for information and not doing anything with them you could use this method.

The EAV method does have a danger that because it appears so easy to add attributes to an entity, it becomes the default way of doing so. It is then used to add attributes for which vital processing is dependent and, because you cannot ensure the integrity of the data using this method, you find the values being used are meaningless and the whole logical basis for the processing is destroyed.

Answer (score -2):

I would create a ClientProperty and ClientWarehousePropertyValue table so that you can store these Client owned properties and their values for each warehouse:

```
ClientProperty
===============
ID
ClientID
Name

ClientWarehousePropertyValue
============================
WarehouseID
ClientPropertyID
Value
```